# Angularjs : How to remove '\r\n' in my output

Tags: angularjs, json

Why and how Angular add **\r\n** at the end of my text ? There's a way to remove them ? Also, i have other fields with a text but the  **\r\n** are not there !!. Example of my json output :

```
{ description : "Description of the country USA \r\n"
id : 12
name : "USA\r\n"
continent : "North of America"
}
```

As you can see, the continent is also a text but i don't the \r\n at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Create angular filter say noCarriageReturn to remove \r\n as below on bind-
JSFiddle For Reference - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1bq8xyny/)

```
sampleApp.filter('noCarriageReturn', function() {
  return function(value) {
    return (!value) ? '' : value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
  };
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to the place you bind that value. At that filter you slice of the last 4 characters of your `var country [0].name`, using the splice(); method.